# Removing focus from first record in table widget?

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a page with the table widget. One the page is open, first record in the table is in focus and highlighted. Is is possible to remove focus from the first record? I would like users to search for records before anything (from the table widget) is highlighted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot remove the default behavior of selecting the first row of the table when it gets loaded; However, if you pretend to only show data after the user starts searching for information, then you might as well not load any data. For that, you will need to uncheck the "Automatically load data" option form the datasource. See picture below:

[image]

Then, what you want to do is load data after the user searches for something.